# Does electric charge have any effect on diamagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, superconductivity, metals

Diamagnetic materials repel magnetic fields because freely moving electrons or cooper pairs within the material can form eddy currents in response to a changing magnetic field.

It is natural to wonder “what happens if we pump up the number of electrons available” by say using a van de graff generator to electrically charge a diamagnetic block of copper.

Since such a material has more electrons perhaps it could have stronger eddy currents.

A different amateur analysis would say that these extra electrons my fill up some orbitals and so the material should instead be LESS diamagnetic.

In either case the question arises, does creating a net electric charge on a diamagnetic metal cause any change to its diamagnetic properties?

Comment: Those additional electrons will be held on surface, there will be very few of them (put more on there and they will jump out - field emission) and they will experience substantial resistance since their motion is limited to thin layer on the surface. Any magnetic effect of these additional electrons requires that they be moving, but they won't, unless they are forces to by time-dependent external field. So I would expect their effect to be very weak.

Comment: That make sense it would be weak but is it tractable to know what that subtle effect would be? Also i wonder if the excess electrons engage in copper pairing at sufficiently low temperatures.